# If statement that has in condition only a variable

Tags: php

Okay, just a simple question..

I am never sure about what it is... can somebody please explain what means

```
if($var) { ... }
```

What are we actually examining here ?!

And yes, another case also :

```
if (!$var) { ... }
```

Tnx! :)

Comment: It means that the variable is a Boolean, or equates to a Boolean; because `if` is basically just a test for TRUE or FALSE

Comment: Imagine `$var = true;` or `$var = false;`.

Comment: I appreciate the community and moderators for their effort, but may I ask why this question is closed? It seems quite okay to me and I really don't think it's vague, incomplete, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is just all about checking the value of the variable. It it supposed to return, a boolean value only. ie. `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

In your case, (any case) it is interpreted as below.

```
if($var){
  // means, if $var is set to true, or has any value at all,
   // execute the code that goes inside here.
  } 


if (!$var){
     // is the opposite of the first example, it means, 
     // if $var is set to false, or is empty, not set.. executing this code... 
   }
```

The below example is from the **[PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)**, and will show you, what the outcome of some expressions will be in PHP when evaluated for a boolean result.

```
<?php
var_dump((bool) "");        // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) 1);         // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) -2);        // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) "foo");     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) 2.3e5);     // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array(12)); // bool(true)
var_dump((bool) array());   // bool(false)
var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)
```

Comment: sounds reasonable.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [phpNoOb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1640606/php-noob). it is used to check if `$var` is TRUE/FALSE and also to check if values have been assigned to `$var`. Good question [Adrian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/907143/adrian).

Answer (score 0):

The `!` means a logical `not`, meaning that the if block will be entered if the variable has a value of `FALSE` **or** will be treated by PHP as `FALSE` due to the loose typing sytem.

The following values will be [treated as `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.boolean.php):

```
FALSE
0
0.0
""
"0"
empty array 
NULL
SimpleXML Objects created from empty tags
```

Answer (score 0):

**If statements**

```
if($var) { ... }
```

When we evaluate an `if` statement, PHP will look at what is inside the brackets of an `if` statement, and try to evaluate it to either `true` or `false`. For example:

```
if(0 == 0)
{
}
```

PHP will check the value on the left, find that it is completely equal to the value on the right, and effectively swap out the `0 == 0` for `true`. So now it reads:

```
if(true)
{
}
```

Now with your example, `$var` contains a boolean value of either `true` or `false`. So in the same way, PHP will swap out `$var` for the value it contains:

```
$var = false;
if($var)
{
}
```

The `if statement` becomes `if(false) {}`. Hence the code isn't ran.

*The ! Operator*

`!` *negates* the value in the if statement, so in the same way as before, let's say:

```
$var = false;

if(!$var){}
```

Now, PHP will swap out `$var` for `false`..

```
if(!false)
```

And it will look at the `!` operator, which turns `false` to `true` and `true` to `false`. So the outcome will be `if(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to others:

```
$var; // second 
// $var = null; // second
// $var = -1; // first
// $var = 0; // second
// $var = 1; // first
// $var = 'hey!'; // first
// $var = ''; // second
// $var = true; // first
// $var = false; // second
// $var = array(); // second
// $var = array('one','two'); // first

if ( $var ) echo 'first';

if ( !$var ) echo 'second';
```